# How to delete record from join table that has foreign keys Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship, delete-row, join

I am trying to delete a record from a table that joins two other tables and it seems that foreign key relationships may stop this operation from happening.

Please keep in mind that the foreign key constraint is not enforced in the database and there is no error thrown oddly enough. It simply does not delete the record. Also, I can easily delete other records from tables that are not join tables.

The current framework that I am using is Asp.Net MVC2, but since I also tried deleting it using an SqlCommand object and it did not work I am not attributing it to the framework. One thing to note is that it does work if I do it through stored procedure, or if I perform a query in SQL Management studio. Also, the app is currently not on the same server as the database.

Any ideas here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that there is no exception being thrown, I wonder where is the call to db.SaveChanges() occurring?  Is it in calling function? (For that matter, where does db come from, and is it in a using() block?).  Larger code sample might help to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two table

```
DataTable1
ID[PK]
Name

DataTable2
ID[FK] 
LastName
```

suppose you have these two tables. If you are deleteing records from **Datatable1** it will give error because you are using **ID**  foreign key in table **Datatable2**

You must first delete record from foreign key table i.e **Datatable2**.